# Referring to environment variables from binding.gyp (node-gyp)

Tags: environment-variables, node-gyp

I am using node-gyp, and I would like to use the value of an environment variable inside my `binding.gyp` file.

Here is the hard way (list context):

```
'<!@(printf "%s" "$FOO")'
```

But is there an easier way?

Answer (score 7):

To the best of my knowledge from working with gyp (the parent Google's project, not the one that ships with node https://code.google.com/p/gyp/). You can access environment variables the same way you would have in the shell.

For example:

```
'$(FOO)'
```

Will return the data stored inside of `FOO`.

To get that information in a list context, I don't know if there is a better way than what you did, except for perhaps a more concise way:

```
'<!(echo $FOO)'
```

You can find the [gyp input format reference online here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220302040759/https://gyp.gsrc.io/docs/InputFormatReference.md).

Comment: Looks like the last link doesn't have the reference, or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like it moved to https://gyp.gsrc.io/docs/InputFormatReference.md