# Using node-gyp Predefined Variable PRODUCT_DIR

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

In `binding.gyp` I want to set like this:

`"libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath,<working directory>/build/Release/" ]`

I am using the following configuration to do the same:

`"libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath,<!(pwd)/build/Release/" ]`

This works but the problem with this is that, it would not work on Windows or wherever `pwd` is not available and also this is not the best option as there is already a predefined variable `PRODUCT_DIR` available in `node-gyp` to achieve this. Strangely I am not able to use this variable `PRODUCT_DIR`.

I tried following options but no luck. error says `Library not loaded: @rpath/<lib>.dylib` (rpath is not getting set):

- `"libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath,>(PRODUCT_DIR)/build/Release/" ]`
- `"libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath,<(PRODUCT_DIR)/build/Release/" ]`
- `"libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath,>(PRODUCT_DIR)"]`
- `"libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath,<(PRODUCT_DIR)"]`

When i tried printing by `"<!(echo <(PRODUCT_DIR) 1>&2)"` it says `builddir: command not found`. Looks like variable has value builddir.
Shouldn't it print the target directory instead of builddir ? or builddir means something for compiler ?

Am I not using this variable properly or is there any other variable available that I should be using ?

Comment: Have you tried `$(PRODUCT_DIR)`? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023442/referring-to-environment-variables-from-binding-gyp-node-gyp

Comment: Tried but no luck :( If I define a user-defined variable I am able to use it `<(user_defined_variable_dir)` but pre defined variable `PRODUCT_DIR` is not working.

Comment: Luckily on Windows my `addon` works even without setting `rpath` :) So for now I have added a condition and setting `rpath` by executing `pwd` where `"OS!='win'"`. https://github.com/royalpinto/node-cares/blob/master/binding.gyp

Answer (score 1):

`PRODUCT_DIR` behaves really weird, I got to say. I avoid it wherever possible. Often by writing external build scripts with plain node.

The reason why you can't `"<!(echo <(PRODUCT_DIR) 1>&2)"` is that is some kind of special variable to node-gyp.

However you are using the right format, like [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-zipfile/blob/master/binding.gyp)...

```
{
   'files': [ '<(PRODUCT_DIR)/libzip.dll' ],
   'destination': '<(module_path)'
}
```

My guess though is that you need to...

```
"variables": {
    "YOUR_DIR: "<(PRODUCT_DIR)/build/Release/"",
    "your_libs": "-Wl,-rpath,<(CURRENT_DIR) ]"
}
```

You know, it's Python, we don't know about :)